# How to split into Sub Documents with Nesting separator?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am migrating data from SQL to COSMOS DB through Azure cosmos DB Data Migration Tool

Can someone please help help to migrate data in Sub-Documents, how to specify in nesting separator

```
SELECT TOP  5 P.ProjectDocumentId, P.ProjectId, PU.UpdatedByFullName
FROM [Docs].[ProjectDocuments] P
INNER JOIN [Docs].[ProjectDocumentUpdate] PU ON P.ProjectDocumentID = PU.ProjectDocumentID
WHERE P.ProjectDocumentId = '7DA0011B-7105-4B6C-AF13-12B5AC50B608'
```

Result:
[image]

Expected Document in Cosmos DB:

```
{
  "ProjectDocumentId": "7da0011b-7105-4b6c-af13-12b5ac50b608",
  "ProjectId": "ed1e0e47-ff1c-47be-b5e9-c235aef76161",
  "ProjectDocumentUpdate": { 
    "UpdatedByFullName" : "Unnati" 
  }, { 
    "UpdatedByFullName" : "Eugene" 
  },
  { 
    "UpdatedByFullName" : "Meghana" 
  }             
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description,your need is not simple producing nested JSON data into cosmos db.You wanna producing JSON contains Json array group by some columns.Something like merge `UpdatedByFullName` by same `ProjectDocumentId` and `ProjectId`.

Based on my test and some researches on the [Migration Tool document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQL),it seems that `Import data from SQL SERVER feature` can't handle with producing json array group by some columns.

So,i figure out a workaround which is lead by this case:[SQL to JSON - Grouping Results into JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669930/sql-to-json-grouping-results-into-json-array) and this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).My sample data as below:

[image]

SQL:

```
select s1.name,
'ageArr' = (
            SELECT
                age AS 'age' 
            FROM
                dbo.student as s2
            where s2.name = s1.name
            FOR JSON PATH)
from dbo.student as s1
group by s1.name
FOR JSON Path;
```

Output as below:

[image]

Then you have such json output so that you can import it into cosmos db simply.

Comment: Thanks @Jay for such a great idea