# Azure Data Factory - SQL to nested JSON

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a SQL database with tables for Staff and Appointments (1 staff : many appointments). I'd like to use Azure Data Factory to output this to nested JSON in a Blob store in a format similar to the below:

```
[
   {
      "staffid":"101",
      "firstname":"Donald",
      "lastname":"Duck",
      "appointments":[
         {
            "appointmentid":"201",
            "startdate":"2020-02-01T00:00:00",
            "enddate":"2020-04-29T23:00:00"
         },
         {
            "appointmentid":"202",
            "startdate":"2020-01-01T00:00:00",
            "enddate":"2020-01-31T00:00:00"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "staffid":"102",
      "firstname":"Mickey",
      "lastname":"Mouse",
      "appointments":[
         {
            "appointmentid":"203",
            "startdate":"2020-02-01T00:00:00",
            "enddate":"2020-04-29T23:00:00"
         },
         {
            "appointmentid":"204",
            "startdate":"2020-01-01T00:00:00",
            "enddate":"2020-01-31T00:00:00"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I've tried using the Copy activity but this produces flat JSON structures rather than the nested structure described above. Has anyone got a way to do this please?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you need help with. Is it how to setup a connection between SQL Server and Azure Data factory? Is it how to setup the job in DF to pull data and generate json? This question is very broad and by narrowing it down to specifics you are more likely to get better answers

Comment: @EdBoykin thanks for getting back to me - I'm specifically trying to find a way to produce *nested* JSON whereby a Staff object contains an array of Appointments. I've got ADF connected to SQL and generating flat JSON records, but want a way to output nested ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More scenarios for JSON data in ADF is flattening. However,according to your description,your need producing JSON contains Json array group by some columns.Something like merge `appointment things` by same `staff`.

If my understanding is right,then you could get some clues from my previous case:[How to split into Sub Documents with Nesting separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169317/how-to-split-into-sub-documents-with-nesting-separator/60184711#60184711). Please refer to my test:

Simulate your sample data:

[image]

Use sql in sql db source dataset:

```
select app.staffid,app.firstname,app.lastname,
'appointments' = (
            SELECT
                appointmentid AS 'appointmentid',startdate as 'startdate',enddate as 'enddate'
            FROM
                dbo.appoint as app2
            where app2.staffid = app.staffid and
            app2.firstname = app.firstname and
            app2.lastname = app.lastname
            FOR JSON PATH)
from dbo.appoint as app
group by app.staffid,app.firstname,app.lastname
FOR JSON Path;
```

[image]

Output in blob storage:

[image]

I try to verify the json format and it is correct.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for this - do you know if there's a way to remove the quotes wrapping the JSON structure / unescape the quotes inside the JSON structure? Otherwise it's subsequently parsed as a single long string, instead of individual JSON objects?

Comment: @Chris The quotes is produced by the sql and could not be removed by the sql. However,you could do the operations for the json string. For example, use a blob trigger azure function. If any file produced into container,it will be formatted by trigger function.

Comment: @Chris Anyway,it is a workaround i could provide here for your reference so far.

Comment: @JayGong isn't there a way to output the JSON without the column name, additional unnecessary quotes and additional unnecessary escape characters (\) ?

Comment: @JayGong thanks - I'll give the Function a try to get rid of all the extra quotes/column name

Comment: You really shouldn't use `'` as a column name delimiter, it's deprecated. And if the column name is the same there is no point aliasing anyway. @Chris If your parser chokes on this then it can't be very good, this is standard JSON