# SQL to generate JSON with same column names and different aliases

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to generate JSON from my SQL data in SSMS in this format :

```json
{
  "id": "1234",
  "first_name": "Hasan",  
  "last_name": "Mahmud",  
  "custom_fields": [
    {
      "custom_field_name": "CPRCertified",
      "custom_field_value": "Y"
    },
    {
      "custom_field_name": "IsAttorney",
      "custom_field_value": "N"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying this:

```sql
SELECT e.Empl_ID AS id,
       e.FirstName AS first_name,
       e.LastName AS last_name,
       'CPRCertified' AS [custom_fields.custom_field_name],
       e.CPRCertified AS [custom_fields.custom_field_value],
       'IsAttorney' AS [custom_fields.custom_field_name],
       e.IsAttorney AS [custom_fields.custom_field_value]
FROM #e e
WHERE e.Empl_ID = '1234'
FOR JSON PATH;
```

But I am getting this error:

> Property 'custom_fields.custom_field_name' cannot be generated in JSON
> output due to a conflict with another column name or alias. Use
> different names and aliases for each column in SELECT list.

I have tried this topics [SQL to JSON - Grouping Results into JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669930/sql-to-json-grouping-results-into-json-array)  but does not work as I have same "custom_field_name" multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible approach is to generate the nested JSON object (`'$."custom_fields"'`) for each row and then build the final JSON:

```
SELECT 
   e.Empl_ID AS id,
   e.FirstName AS first_name,
   e.LastName AS last_name,
   (
      SELECT * 
      FROM (VALUES
         ('CPRCertified', e.CPRCertified),
         ('IsAttorney', e.IsAttorney)
      ) v (custom_field_name, custom_field_value)
      FOR JSON PATH
   ) AS custom_fields
FROM (VALUES
   ('1234', 'Hasan', 'Mahmud', 'Y', 'N')
) e (Empl_ID, FirstName, LastName, CPRCertified, IsAttorney)
WHERE e.Empl_ID = '1234'
FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Some words about escaping and `JSON_QUERY()` - as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-json_query-with-for-json) explains *... JSON_QUERY returns a valid JSON fragment. As a result, FOR JSON doesn't escape special characters in the JSON_QUERY return value. If you're returning results with FOR JSON, and you're including data that's already in JSON format (in a column or as the result of an expression), wrap the JSON data with JSON_QUERY without the path parameter.*.

Note, that as @Larnu commented, this step is not needed here.

Comment: Was literally about to edit something very similar into my own as an alternative. :) Though, as far as I can see, the `JSON_QUERY` isn't needed: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc310cb73465785e2911cad82ff5621f)

Comment: @Larnu, honestly, my first attempt was the approach in your answer. :)

Comment: @Larnu Reason it doesn't need it is that a direct `FOR JSON` subquery is recognized as being JSON, see eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5771d14b41902fb4608f7d1577bd09f6 where it's not recognized

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to `UNPIVOT` your data (using a `VALUES` table construct) and then switch to `JSON AUTO`:

```sql
SELECT e.Empl_ID AS id,
       e.FirstName AS first_name,
       e.LastName AS last_name,
       custom_fields.custom_field_name,
       custom_fields.custom_field_value
FROM #e e
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(N'CPRCertified',e.CPRCertified),
                        (N'IsAttorney',e.IsAttorney))custom_fields(custom_field_name,custom_field_value)
FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```